# Time out with Laravel mail::queue() loop

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I have a function that allows me to send an individual email to every member in my db.   My mailing list has grown and I now get a timeout after ~700 emails are added to the queue.   Is there a way that I can make my loop more efficient do I need to just increase my timeout limit?

Here is what my function does:

- gathers inputs from form
- Saves email to db (1 time)
- loops through my list of users and adds each of them to my mail queue.

Here is the loop:

```
foreach($members as $member){

            if (!empty($member->contact_email)){

            $mData = array(
                    'from' => $from,
                    'fromName' => $fromName,
                    'email' => $member->contact_email,
                    'name' => $member->contact_firstName,
                    'body' => $body,
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    'meta' => $meta
                        );
                $mail = array(
                    'email' => $member->contact_email,
                    'name' => $member->contact_firstName,
                    'body' => $body,
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    );

                Mail::queue('emails.memberMessage', $mail, function($message) use ($mData)
                {
                  $message->from($mData['from'], $mData['fromName']);
                  $message->to($mData['email'], $mData['name'])->subject($mData['subject']);
                  $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-Metadata', $mData['meta']);
                });

                $status = SUCCESS;

        }
        }
```

Comment: Is this run from the browser? Or a batch/cron job

Comment: The function is run from a browser.

Comment: How large is `$members`? And are you  getting a PHP timeout, or are we talking about a browser timeout?

Comment: Currently about 1500.   It is part of a trade association membership management tool I'm working on.  Hoping to have $members up to 6000 in the near future.

Comment: Getting a PHP timeout

Comment: I would personally convert the process to a batch/cron function

Comment: You can probably get away with with using `set_time_limit(0)` before your loop to allow it to take as long as it needs. There's nothing I can see that's specifically inefficient, or rather nothing I can see you can really make efficiencies to.